# Visual Studio 2010's support for .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

Having read numerous posts on the net and here at Stack Overflow about this I still am unsure as to whether VS 2010 supports .NET 4.5. MS states on http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=30653 that it is an in place upgrade .NET 4.

Does this mean that once .NET 4.5 has been installed on a machine with VS2010 installed I can still leave my target as .NET 4 but it will actually be using 4.5? For various reasons I cannot upgrade to VS 2012.

All pointers greatly appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't look like it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/hh487282.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET 4.5 does not install side by side with .NET 4.0, it replaces it. But it still allows you to target .NET 4.0 with it installed, so it shouldn't break the installation AFAIK. But you can't utilize any of the .NET 4.5 features since you can't target anything higher than .NET 4.0 in Visual Studio 2010.

If you need to use these features, you will have to install Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 8):

You can't target .NET 4.5 with VS2010.